# Could not generate 6 digit random number using PHP

Tags: php

I have an issue. I could not generate the 6 digit random number using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$login_code = getLoginToken(6);
function getLoginToken($length) {
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
    $max = strlen($codeAlphabet); // edited
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0, $max - 1)];
    }
    return $token;
}
```

Here while i am trying to fetch the `login_code` its displaying the error 'the page is not working'. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: define function getLgoinToken() before using it

Comment: `crypto_rand_secure` is not a php function. Did you create it yourself?

Comment: @Daan : Yes you are right. I got it now.

Comment: Why not just use `substr(uniqid("",true),rand(0,16),6)` ?

Comment: @apokryfos that code will generate some dodgy looking strings like `.32608`

Comment: @apokryfos If he's trying to generate a secure token, he should definitely avoid using `rand` (edit: and `uniqid`, too).

Comment: In the absence of context all we can do is speculate.

Comment: well, I for one am not grasping the question. This code looks ok to me. Something is not being told/shown.